# SQL query to get records of before last 30 days( Not last 30 days )

Tags: mysql, sql, select, intervals

I want to find the different percentages of my last 30 days value with the previous last 30 days value. I have already got the sum of the last 30 days' value. How do I get the sum of the previous last 30 days?

This was the query for selecting last 30 days sum.

```
SELECT SUM(paymentAmount) as usd30day
FROM `tbl_pi_payment` 
WHERE currencyCode = 'USD' and renewalDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Example: today is 25the of OCT.
I have the sum of values for 25th OCT to 26th Sep.
Now I need the sum of values for 26th Sep to 25th Aug

Comment: Basically, you want a value for which the date is less than "today minus 30 days" ? This was a hint!

Comment: You won't last 30 to last 30?

Comment: @AxelH Yes, I want a value for 30 days less than "today minus 30 days"

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

you can try below -

```
SELECT SUM(case when renewalDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY paymentAmount else 0 end) as usd30day ,
SUM(case when renewalDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY and renewalDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY paymentAmount else 0 end) as usd60day
FROM tbl_pi_payment
WHERE currencyCode = 'USD'
```

Comment: I just want a value for 30 day less than "today minus 30 days".

Answer (score 1):

getting previous transactions based on `renewalDate`

```
select sum(case when renewalDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY then paymentAmount else 0 end) as usd30day 
    , sum(case when datediff(now() - renewalDate) <= 30 then paymentAmount else 0 end) as usd30prevday 
from tbl_pi_payment 
where 
    currencyCode = 'USD'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT datediff(NOW(), renewalDate) % 30 as every30day, SUM(paymentAmount) as usd30day
FROM `tbl_pi_payment`
WHERE currencyCode = 'USD' 
GROUP BY datediff(NOW(), renewalDate) % 30
```